# Which is a better suited ultra endurance bike?

Tags: road-bike, long-distance

I’m planning to buy a new ultra endurance road bike. Confused between Trek Domane SL 5 and Scott Addict 10. I’m getting both the bikes at negligible cost difference. The only difference is that Domane is coming with complete 105 group set while Addict 10 is complete Ultegra

Which bike I should go for?

Comment: Ride the one that is most comfortable to you.  If they're the same, ride the one with the best warranty.

Comment: @Criggie while your point is true in a general sense, there's a big difference between comfort over a typical test ride and comfort all day every day as the OP seems to want. Mine is a good fit and felt great for an hour  but needed a bit of tweaking to get comfortable for 12 hours. After riding 38 hours out of 68 I reckon more needs to be done, and that's still much less than "ultra endurance". So you'd really need at least a 3 day test ride.

Comment: @ChrisH agreed - but you can normally pick a bike that is "no" much easier than "yes"  So eliminating one is the same as choosing the other one.

Comment: @Criggie true, so long as one is right, and if not it's better to find out before buying it

Answer (score 2):

In theory for an ultra endurance bike, the Trek Domane would be a better choice as this is exactly the type of riding it was designed for with several features to improve rider comfort.

In practice, its never that simple.  Many years ago I went to a Scott test ride event with every intention of testing and buying a Scott CR1 (their sportive/endurance frame at the time).  I rode it in the morning, and it just didn't feel right.  I went out again in the afternoon and rode the Addict (their dedicated race bike at the time) and it fitted like a glove and was just a better bike for me.

My advice would be to always test ride a bike that you plan to spend a significant amount of money on.  If you can't get a good test ride on those two models, then go and find a test ride on other bikes with a very similar geometry to help you make the decision.

Comment: Agreed. Modern high quality racing carbon frames+forks are surprisingly comfortable even though their main goal is to be light and aero. So I wouldn't rule out a racing road bike. In the end proper fit, tires, tire pressure and the saddle will be most important.

Answer (score 1):

Do try to test ride the 2 bikes before making your choice. I tested both of them not so long ago, and I personally had a preference for the **Trek** one, although the saddle felt horrible, but the shop at the time was OK to swap it. The **Scott** felt more agressive, and I was fearing when trying it a lack of comfort on longer term. Now, we all have a different physiognomy, and my opinion is based on a 15 minutes ride only.

As for the groupset, even Shimano themselves will agree that they are very little differences. I remember watching a video of an EU Shimano representative admitting that the *105* and *Ultegra* are exactly the same in terms of dimensions and design. The only thing that changes are the manufacturing process and materials making the *Ultegra* a bit lighter. The overall quality of both is the same, and you shouldn't sacrifice comfort over a fancier label.